# Searching and Selecting multiple data in Worksheets w/ common header

Tags: vba

I just started using VBA for making my life easier, programming is not my background at all. When I run codes I may write too much. 
So I have two questions, check the code below.

Sub Find()
'
' Find Macro
'

'
    'L.NAM.O

```
Worksheets("LAC").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Find(What:="forecast_quarter", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("NewForecast").Select
Range("K2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'L.NAM.M

Worksheets("EMEA").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Find(What:="forecast_quarter", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("NewForecast").Select
Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I want to be able to find the forecast_quarter in both sheets(I have 3 in total) and paste in one Worksheet(New Forecast), one below other. The thing is, I think this is too much, might have an easier way than run all the process all over again.

My idea would be, "search the forecast_quarter quarter in the worksheets I want and paste on below the other). As I have all criterias to do that, this could me massive. Any easier, better way to run it?
Thanks!

Comment: "forecast_quarter" is part of a column header?  It's difficult to tell exactly what you're doing here.

Comment: Hi. Forecast_quarter is the header that appears in every single Worksheet I have. I am basically searching it, copying the data below and pasting in a different Worksheet(NewForecast).

Comment: So when you're selecting A2 that's the cell below the "forecast_quarter" header?

Comment: Yes. But this could be different, as Forecast_Quarter could be in a different column, that is one of my issues..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested) should work.

```
Sub CopyAll()

    CopyDataByHeader "LAC", "forecast_quarter"
    CopyDataByHeader "EMEA", "forecast_quarter"

End Sub

'Look for a specific header on a sheet, and if found copy
'  the data below it to "NewForecast" sheet
Sub CopyDataByHeader(shtName As String, hdrText As String)

    Dim f As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtName)
        'search for the header
        Set f = .Cells.Find(What:=hdrText, After:=.Cells(1), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            'found the header: copy the data below it
            .Range(f.Offset(1, 0), .Cells(.Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
                 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NewForecast").Cells( _
                                   Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Else
            'header not found...
            MsgBox "Header text '" & hdrText & "' not found on sheet '" & shtName & "' !"
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```